# Matching regular expression in android

Tags: java, android, regex

I am using an regex to match edit text content which specifies NAME of user. But every time it is returning false.

```
public static final String NAME_REG = "^\\s*[a-zA-Z\\s]+\\s*$";
```

I am matching this using this function

```
public static boolean textValidator(String pattern, String text){
    final Pattern REGEX = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    if (!REGEX.matcher("abcdef").matches()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Please figure out where I am doing wrong.

Comment: `REGEX.matcher()` is returning true or something that is evaluating to true.  Please show what you've troubleshooted.

Comment: it is returning true...

Comment: By true I meant false.  And by false, I meant I didn't properly match your parentheses in my head.  `REGEX.matcher().matches()` is returning false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
 public static boolean textValidator(String text){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\S+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    if (matcher.find()){
      return true; 
    } 
    return false; 
    }
```